# Accessing array element by index is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Output of console.log(fontName); is as below, where fontName is an array

[image: output of console.log(fontName); where fontName is an array defined as var fontName = new Array();]

But output of console.log(fontName[0]); is undefined

[image]

How to access each element of fontName array ?

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

I assume that fontName is filled asynchronously. Since the logging of an object isn't synchronous per se (it is logged by reference, so you can see changes even if they are applied later on) you see the content of the object in the logs, but if you access it directly it is still undefined by then.
Regarding your question: Yes, this is a proper way to access an element of an object. So the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: This is the most likely explanation, it should say just that if you hover over the `i` in the dev console

Comment: @Patrick Kelleter, fontName is defined in a callback function of ajax call and values are the file name in a directory.

Comment: When it's defined in a callback function that means it is defined asynchronously as i assumed. So when you acces that object outside of the callback function it can be undefined for the time it has not been finished yet. You should take a closer look at asynchronous behaviour of javascript in general in order to get a feeling whats going on in this particular case